# Python: conceptualizing has-many relations

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm studying python, and at the moment I'm a bit stuck with understanding 'has-many' relationships.

I do understand **is-a** relation:

```
> class New(Old):
```

Or **is-many** relation:

```
> class Old(Older):
> 
> class New(Old):
```

I think I also understand **has-a** relation:

```
class Older(object):
    def __init__(self, something):
        self.something = something

class Newest(object):
    def __init__(self, something):
        self.something = something
        self.something_else = Older()
```

But how does **has-many** relationship look like? How to understand/conceptualize it?

It seems that I just can't wrap my head around this ... :/

Comment: Could the **has-many** relationship be like **has-a** with an array instead of an object (A persone has many clothes for instance). Is there another OOP term that could be used to describe the **has-many** relationship ? I never heard it that way

Answer (score 1):

This question is all a bit vague; these are not terms that would usually be used in this context. If you want a class that can hold many instances of another class, you can simply use an attribute that is a list, for example:

```
class Holder:
    def __init__(self, objects=None):
        self.objects = objects or []
```

Comment: Would it be fair to say then, that has-many relations always refer to a list or a dictionary of some kind (on a -many side of the term refered to denote such context, even if such denotation is not generally used)?